# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am very new to ionic and angularjs. When I run my application in browser it works fine but after build for android and run it in devices i get blank page. And when i check console using I get the following error.

[image]

And this is my code

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'page_sidemenu': {
                templateUrl: "index_sidemenu.html"
            },
            'page_content': {
                templateUrl: "main_page.html"
            }

        }

    });

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'page_sidemenu': {
                templateUrl: 'profile_sidemenu.html',
                controller: 'profilemenuCtr'
            },
            'page_content': {
                templateUrl: 'profile_page.html',
                controller: 'profileCtr'
            }
        }
    });

$stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: "/login?id",
        views: {
            'page_sidemenu': {
                templateUrl: "index_sidemenu.html"
            },
            'page_content': {
                templateUrl: "login_page.html",
                controller: "loginCtr"
            }

        }

    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Anybody please help me to resolve this.

Comment: had you added the platforms (IOS and Android) in Ionic Project. Thanks

Comment: There is just too many things wrong in this code. Why don't you just ionic start myApp so it builds a working project for you, then you can serve it and see how it works first